# Web messaging comet cross-domain bayeux webmsgServlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, dojo, websphere, bayeux

I'm writing a mobile application using phonegap that subscribes to a SIBus jms Topic.

First I was able to run a demo after configuration but I'm not able to run It from a different domain because the application must be runnig on an external domain from the server.

I had many problems with cross domain ajax call to webservices the solution was to change the header to `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
I'm worndering how to fix this to change the header to the incoming requests

```
dojo.require("dojox.cometd");
   dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
      dojox.cometd.init("http://localhost:9080/ClientWeb/webmsgServlet");
      dojox.cometd.subscribe("/T.Frs", window, "display");
     }
   );
   function display(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
       alert("Message " + msg.data.test);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Jetty's [CrossOriginFilter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter), it is a portable filter you can run in any servlet container that implements the CORS specification, allowing you to access cross origin resources seamlessly.

CometD ships this filter by default in the demo, so you can have a look there to see how is configured, or look at the [CometD reference](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/), section 5.4.1.3.

Comment: I setup crossOriginFilter but I have allways the same problem